# migrating instance from 2008r to 2016 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

i have a client that wants to migrate his data to sql server 2016 . currently they have 2008r and the databases are huge(total of 4 tb) on the instance.
what is the best way to performe this with the least amount of down time?
i thought about mirroring but im not sure it can be done 
between the two versions.
if so what are the steps to do so ? if im missing information please let me know.
thanks

Comment: have you thought about potentially restoring a full backup on the new server, and then log shipping from old server to new? Then, just before you 'go-live' you could take a tail of the log backup on the old box, and restore on the new live server? ... I should have also asked, how many databases are you talking about?

Comment: @dimuser 20 databases and 3 of them are together 3.5 tb.. i thought about logshipping but i was afraid because of the size that maybe it would cause problems with the restore time of the log. but i think its a better idea.. cause if i fail over the miror on the 2016 it would be hard to go back right

Comment: @winter_sql you can't fail back from a higher version to a lower version with either log shipping or mirroring. It's a one way trip. Both options are compatible moving from 08R2 to 2016 though.

Comment: both of you i mean

Comment: @dimuser if i choose logshipping ill have to restore on the new server then restore diff  and then do the log shipping for each one ?